# Why ReflectionChild.class.isInstance(Class.class) is not true?

Tags: java, class

Why ReflectionChild.class.isInstance(Class.class) is not true?

As we know in reflection Class.class.isInstance(Class.class) is true. Now see on below code snip.

```
   ReflectionChild ch = new ReflectionChild(); //Take random class

    if(ch.getClass()==ReflectionChild.class){
        System.out.println("ch.getClass()==ReflectionChild.class");
    }

    System.out.println(ReflectionChild.class.getClass());
    System.out.println(Class.class);

    if(ReflectionChild.class.getClass()==Class.class){
        System.out.println("ReflectionChild.class.getClass()==Class.class");
        //System.exit(0);
    }
    if(ReflectionChild.class.isInstance(Class.class)){
        System.out.println("true");
        //System.exit(0);
    }else{
       System.out.println("false");
    }
```

The output is :-

```
ch.getClass()==ReflectionChild.class  // 1st SYSOUT

class java.lang.Class                 // 2nd SYSOUT

class java.lang.Class                 // 3rd SYSOUT  

ReflectionChild.class.getClass()==Class.class  //4th SYSOUT

false   // 5th SYSOUT
```

According to above 1st four SYSOUT's the line `ReflectionChild.class.isInstance(Class.class)` should be true. But for me it is false as output .

Can any one explain?

Comment: Have you tried `isAssignableFrom()`? Maybe `equals()`?

Comment: `ReflectionChild.class.getClass() != ReflectionChild.class` also.

Comment: `ReflectionChild.class.isInstance(Class.class)` is the same as `Class.class instanceof ReflectionChild`, which is obviously false.

Answer (score 3):

`Class.class` is an instance of `Class`, not `ReflectionChild`.
Therefore, `isInstance()` returns false.

Comment: but ReflectionChild.class.getClass() gives the Class.class what is that ?

Comment: @mahi: `ReflectionChild.class` is an instance of `Class`.

Comment: @mahi because ReflectionChild.class isn't the same as ReflectionChild.class.getClass(). Did you mean to check if `ReflectionChild.class.getClass().isInstance(Class.class)`, or possibly `Class.class.isInstance(ReflectionChild.class)`?

Answer (score 2):

Because a `Class` instance is not an instance of of type `ReflectionChild`.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-)

> Specifically, if this `Class` object represents a declared class, this
>   method returns `true` if the specified `Object` argument is an instance of
>   the represented class (or of any of its subclasses); it returns `false`
>   otherwise.

The argument you've provided is of type `Class` which is not an instance of the type `ReflectionChild` represented by the `Class` instance returned by the class literal expression `ReflectionChild.class`.

Comment: but ReflectionChild.class.getClass() gives the Class.class what is that ?

Comment: @mahi What did you expect it to give? A class literal (`ReflectionChild.class`) produces a `Class` instance. `getClass` on an instance of type `Class` will return the `Class` object for `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadocs of  `Class#isInstance(Object)`:

> Determines if the specified `Object` is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this `Class`. This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language instanceof operator. The method returns true if the specified Object argument is non-null and can be cast to the reference type represented by this `Class` object without raising a `ClassCastException`. It returns false otherwise.

So the object passed as an *argument* to the method must be an instance of the class represented by the object on which the method is called, **not the other way around**: the expression that should return `true` is the following:

```
if(Class.class.isInstance(ReflectionChild.class)){
```